# Seg fault on malloc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am reading integers from a file, and when I try to grow my array, I am getting a segmentation fault on the **second** call to `growMyArray(struct myArray)`, specifically at `int *grownArray = malloc(arrayToGrow.maxCount * sizeof(int));`:

```
struct myArray growMyArray(struct myArray arrayToGrow) {

    arrayToGrow.maxCount *= 2;

    int *grownArray = malloc(arrayToGrow.maxCount * sizeof(int));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < arrayToGrow.count; i++)
        grownArray[i] = arrayToGrow.numbers[i];

    free(arrayToGrow.numbers);

    arrayToGrow.numbers = grownArray;

    return arrayToGrow;
}
```

My structure:

```
typedef struct myArray {
    int count;
    int maxCount;
    int *numbers;
} myArray;
```

Reading from input redirection:

```
struct myArray getRandomNumbers() {

    struct myArray randomNumbers;
    randomNumbers.count = 0;
    randomNumbers.maxCount = DEFAULT_SIZE;
    randomNumbers.numbers = malloc(randomNumbers.maxCount * sizeof(int));

    while (scanf("%d", &randomNumbers.numbers[randomNumbers.count]) == 1) {

        randomNumbers.count++;

        if (randomNumbers.count > randomNumbers.maxCount)
            randomNumbers = growMyArray(randomNumbers);
    }

    return randomNumbers;
}
```

I find this particularly odd because growing the array always works the first time but never works the second time.  I have used multiple values for `DEFAULT_SIZE`, ranging from 2 to 20000 on a set of test data of size 200000.

Is there an apparent reason why I am getting a segmentation fault on the **second** call to `growMyArray`, specifically at `int *grownArray = malloc(arrayToGrow.maxCount * sizeof(int));`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote past the end of the array.

```
while (scanf("%d", &randomNumbers.numbers[randomNumbers.count]) == 1) {

    randomNumbers.count++;

    if (randomNumbers.count > randomNumbers.maxCount)
        randomNumbers = growMyArray(randomNumbers);
}
```

Because you use `>` in the test, the `if` only fires once `randomNumbers.count = randomNumbers.maxCount + 1`, i.e. the `scanf` writes to `randomNumbers.numbers[randomNumbers.maxCount]` which is past the end of the array.

Therefore, change `>` to `>=` in the `if` statement there.

Answer (score 0):

take care of youre data type

```
typedef struct myArray {
    int count;
    int maxCount;
    int *numbers;
} myArray;
```

this means that count and maxcount are signed integers and they can reach negative values which is not correct for count and can lead also to some memory corruption.

Comment: I do not believe that this is the issue, but an excellent point.  Thanks, Adrian